# iOS 8 Lock Orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have inherited an iOS app that was built pre-iOS 6. As of now it is not functional for iOS 8. My goal is to get the current app working in its current state in iOS 8 then write a whole new version of the app bringing it into the modern age.

I am a bit of an Objective-C newbie so I'm working through each fix as I go. The main problem I am having with the app in its current state is that the main view controller is in portrait on open. The entire app should be locked to landscape right, but when you open it starts in portrait. If you click home and re-open the app it's then in landscape right.

In the Info.plist, landscape right is the only supported orientation. I have also locked the view controller to landscape right using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

None of these fixes have gotten the view controller to open in landscape right, however.

Any ideas on how to get the view controller to open in landscape right?

The app is so old, it does not have a UINavigationController set-up. Is that necessary to set the orientation? Any help or tips are appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
Here is my info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>VersePack</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.TiBrew.versePack</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.2.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string>MainWindow-iPad</string>
    <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which devices are you working on? People tend to get stuck with this when working with iPads.

Try deleting the code you have above, and go into info.plist itself to (the info tab, not general) and check that "Supported interfaced orientations (iPad)" and "Supported interfaced orientations (iPhone)" only contain 1 item each that is "Landscape (right home button)".

The code you have is generally only used if you want to lock the app to different orientations at different points, if you want the whole thing locked to a single orientation the it isn't needed, so also have a good check through your code to make sure you delete every last trace.

Also, it shouldn't matter that you don't have a UINavigationController set up.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's an iPhone only app. I had a feeling that I was making it more complicated than it had to be. I'll try your answer and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: I removed all references to orientation in the view controllers and there is not orientation properties in the app delegate. Then I made sure all the info.plist Supported Interface Orientations were set to "Landscape (right home button)". However, on opening the app the main view controller is still opening in portrait. I can't find any reason why it is because the app is set to only support landscape. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Could you upload your info.plist please?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out my problem. I needed to set the main view controller as the root for the window. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. The main view controller that appeared on open was not set as the root view controller for the app. I added:

```
self.window.rootViewController = myViewController;
```

to my appDelegate.m and the window appeared in the right orientation.